# How to detect whether ConversationalRetrievalChain called the OpenAI LLM?

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, large-language-model, conversational-ai

I have the following code:

```
chat_history = []
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
db = FAISS.from_documents(chunks, embeddings)
qa = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(OpenAI(temperature=0.1), db.as_retriever())
result = qa({"question": "What is stack overflow", "chat_history": chat_history})
```

The code creates embeddings, creates a FAISS in-memory vector db with some text that I have in `chunks` array, then it creates a ConversationalRetrievalChain, followed by asking a question.

Based on what I understand from ConversationalRetrievalChain, when asked a question, it will first query the FAISS vector db, then, if it can't find anything matching, it will go to OpenAI to answer that question.  (is my understanding correct?)

How can I detect if it actually called OpenAI to get the answer or it was able to get it from the in-memory vector DB? The `result` object contains `question`, `chat_history` and `answer` properties and nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Based on what I understand from ConversationalRetrievalChain, when asked a question, it will first query the FAISS vector db, then, if it can't find anything matching, it will go to OpenAI to answer that question."

This part is not correct. Each time ConversationalRetrievalChain receives your query in conversation, it will rephrase the question, and retrieves documents from your vector store(It is FAISS in your case), and returns answers generated by LLMs(It is OpenAI in your case). Meaning that ConversationalRetrievalChain is the conversation version of RetrievalQA.

Comment: So it goes back to OpenLLM every single time?

Comment: @AngryHacker Right, each time it ConversationalRetrievalChain will invoke the LLM(like OpenAI) to generate an answer with documents retrieved given in the context.

Comment: @AngryHacker right, it goes back to OpenLLM after retrieving the documents from vector store.

Answer (score 2):

You can detect if the answer was obtained from the in-memory vector database by checking if the "answer" property exists and is not empty in the result object. If it's present, the answer came from the database; otherwise, it was generated by the OpenAI model.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I personaly don't think ConversationalRetrievalChain could get you any answer from document without sending api request to OpenAI in provided example. But I'm not expert with it, I could be wrong.

But you could use another cheaper/local llm as a way to condense final question to help optimize token count.

Here is their example:

```
qa = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
    ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model="gpt-4"),
    vectorstore.as_retriever(),
    condense_question_llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model='gpt-3.5-turbo'),
)
```

A way one could trace usage of API is as follows:

```
from langchain.callbacks import get_openai_callback
with get_openai_callback() as cb:
    result = llm("Tell me a joke")
    print(cb)
```

Tokens Used: 42
Prompt Tokens: 4
Completion Tokens: 38
Successful Requests: 1
Total Cost (USD): $0.00084

The other usefull way is to use additional tool to trace requests: https://github.com/amosjyng/langchain-visualizer

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can apply for https://smith.langchain.com/ to visual tracking of the `ConversationalRetrievalChain`

See the image:[image]

Here I'm using `AzureChatOpenAI`.
The first call of the LLMChain is for "Given the following conversation and a follow up question, rephrase the follow up question to be a standalone question, in its original language.

The second call is for your specific prompt or the langchain default prompt.

In addition you can set `verbose=True` on `ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm` to see the what is happening.

Hope it helps.
Regards.